# Class functions and Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am currently stuck on a problem with Python and Tkinter.
I want to create a simple application with its UI made on Tkinter. To do so, I created a class to define my application and I want to create my GUI layout in a separate class function.
However, when I call it, it has no effect on my Tk window (in this particular example, the title is not modified)
Here is the code

```
from Tkinter import *

fen =Tk()

class test_Tk_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.make_title

    def make_title(self):
        fen.title("Test")


a = test_Tk_class()
fen.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `()` after `self.make_title`:

```
from Tkinter import *

fen =Tk()

class test_Tk_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.make_title() # <------------

    def make_title(self):
        fen.title("Test")


a = test_Tk_class()
fen.mainloop()
```